# select box shows some unreal background image

Tags: css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, dropdown

[image]

Select box shows some unreal background image in chrome only.
I used following css. 
Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

```
select
{
   font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background: transparent;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url("../Images/select-ico.png") no-repeat scroll 96% center #fff;
}
```

Comment: can you please create a code snipset or a fiddle?

Comment: Your screenshot is not clear. Are the lines the unreal background you're complaining about, or is that supposed to be an arrow pointing to the problem?

Comment: That is, I don't see the problem. The only difference I see between SeaMonkey and Chromium is that in SeaMonkey, the focus rectangle on the select is smaller than the background image, for whatever reason.

Comment: I think its a chrome version issue, i have checked on another version of chrome it works fine.